# What happens if my Visual C++ custom memory allocator returns a block not properly aligned?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, alignment

In my Visual C++ program I use a custom `operator new` that uses `malloc()` to allocate memory. My custom `operator new` stores extra data in the first 4 bytes of memory and returns an offset pointer as the beginning of the block (the program is 32 bit):

```
 void* operator new( size_t size )
 {
     size += sizeof( int );//assume it doesn't overflow
     int* result = static_cast<int*>( malloc( size ) );
     if( result == 0 ) {
         throw std::bad_alloc;
     }
     *result = ... //write extra data
     return result + 1;
 }
```

Now if caller code wants to store a variable of size 64 bits (`__int64` or `double`) the block will not be properly aligned for that.

What problems can this cause in a 32-bit Windows program?

Comment: AFAIK - there may be some performance degradation. x86 fixes the misalignment automatically.

Comment: It can cause a crash if SIMD instructions are used that require 8- or 16-byte aligned memory addresses (most do), otherwise just performance degradation.

Comment: Join the club.  I also have my own memory allocator (mainly to simplify debugging of memory-related problems, logging statistics, leak reporting, ...).  I use a header that I always pad to a multiple of 8 bytes and never had problems with it.  But I don't know for 4 bytes.

Comment: @Patrick: Yes, I know how to fix it, but such fix will increase memory usage and will need to be tested, so I'd like to evaluate the impact first.

Comment: @sharptooth, you could check whether the requested size is a multiple of 8 or not.  If it isn't, allocate 4 bytes extra and use this to store your extra data.  If it is a multiple of 8, allocate 8 bytes extra and use the last 4 bytes of those extra 8 to store your extra data.  This might already improve memory usage.

Comment: @Patrick: This won't always help. If the caller want to allocate an instance of a class that stores two pointers it will request 8 bytes, yet 4-bytes alignment would be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On 32 bit windows it will just potentially be slower as the hardware can deal with unaligned data accesses, just more slowly.

On other operating systems / platforms it will likely cause a crash (Or VERY slow performance as the OS catches the unaligned memory access and simulates it for you in some cases)